# Laravel = Parent - Child On The Same Table

Tags: laravel

MAIN TABLE

```
id  | parent_id | form_id   | is_approved   | fruit_id
------------------------------------------------------
1   | 0         | 1         | 1             | 1
2   | 1         | 2         | 1             | 2
3   | 0         | 1         | 1             | 3
4   | 3         | 2         | 0             | 4
```

FRUIT TABLE

```
id  | name
------------
1   | cherry
2   | guava
3   | apple
4   | grapes
```

by referencing on the Main Table, i need to output all fruit names from the Fruit Table for rows that has a:

1.) parent_id != 0

2.) is_approved=1

how to do this? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a fruit model, with a main relation you could do this which would give you a collection of Fruit models meeting your criteria.

```
$fruits = Fruit::whereHas('main', function ($query) {
    $query->where('parent_id', '!=', 0)
          ->where('is_approved', 1);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fruitNames = DB::table('main')->where([['parent_id', '>=', 1],['is_approved', '=', 1]])->join('fruit_names')->get(['fruit_names.name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work!

```
$fruitNames = main::select('main.id', 'b.name')
      ->join('fruit_names as b', 'b.id', '=', 'main.fruit_id')
      ->join('main as c', 'c.id', '=', 'main.parent_id')
      ->where('main.parent_id', '!=', 0)
      ->where('c.is_approved', 1)
      ->get();
```

I wonder if this query can be improved.